# Ubuntu restarts 3am everyday

Tags: tag

I am new to Ubuntu.

I have installed the server version with no GUI.
At 3am every morning the server restarts itself.

I don't know where to look to see if its some setting in ubuntu.
I ran the 'last' command and at the bottom of the display it says - wtmp begins Fri July 3 03:00:02 2020

If its a setting in ubuntu how can I turn it off and I don't know why it would restart at the same time every day. I am using version 18.04.4

Thanks

Comment: I would check the `/etc/crontab` file and see if something runs at 03:00 (displays as `0 3 * * * root command_to_execute`) and if the command is `run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily` I would check the scripts in `/etc/cron.daily/`.

Comment: At the dollar sign I typed  last head  but that brings up the same message of wtmp begins  Fri July...... same result when I type last reboot head but same message. I tried this command at the dollar sign sudo crontab -e but there is just lots of text lines with # symbol in front. The first line says # Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron. The last # line reads # m h dom mon dow command

Comment: This is initiated by `unattended-upgrades`; it will install new upgrades for packages and then reboot (standard at 3:00 local time). If you set a correct mail address in `crontab` the system will inform you of its intention to reboot. Moreover, when you login the day before the reboot, the system will tell you every hour on the hour that a reboot is imminent. However, every day is a bit excessive. My server reboots once every three weeks or so. You can do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` yourself and see if something is wrong that forces a daily reboot.

Comment: I ran the /etc/cron.daily/ as was suggested but that brings up a message of  -bash: etc/cron.daily/: is a directory.

Comment: What is the output of `grep ":Unattended-Upgrade " /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*`?

Comment: I typed grep ":Unattended-Upgrade  " /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/* and pressed enter but it just brings the name of my login $ ready for something to be typed there. I did get the sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade command to work and  nothing about times or reboot but it says there are 11 updates. I just selected N for now and I can run that later.

Comment: But now you still don't know what causes the daily reboots. Please rerun the command and press Y this time.

Comment: I think I will backup my data first, then run it. I have got files stored on the harddrive. in the meantime I rerun the grep command and used a capital U for upgrade. It must be case sensitive and I got this result. /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades:APT::Periodic:Unattended-Upgrade "1";

Comment: I think that 1 means every day

Comment: You can edit the relevant file and change "1" to "0" for ***manual*** updates. But, in this case do not forget to run `sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` at least once per week. I use manual update and run this command sequence several times per week. However, the system rebooting your server ***every day*** means that there is a problem with the automatic update. Run the above command sequence manually to see what kind of error(s) you have...

Comment: Ok I will learn how to do that. What is the relevance of using the autoclean and auto remove. Does that have to be done? I am wondering if I set the updates to manual, if I have to run other commands once a week then maybe I leave things how they are. I don't touch the server for months. The reboot is an annoyance factor if I happen to be working on those documents at the time. Otherwise the system works fine.

Comment: See man pages for `apt` and `apt-get`.

Comment: Ok I will learn how to do that. What is the relevance of using the autoclean and auto remove. Does that have to be done? I am wondering if I set the updates to manual, if I have to run other commands once a week then maybe I leave things how they are. I don't touch the server for months. The reboot is an annoyance factor if I happen to be working on those documents at the time. Otherwise the system works fine. I will run that command you suggest. I'll do my backups first then come back on it, once its completed. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: If you run the commands yourself, you might as well uninstall `unattended-upgrades` and reboot the server whenever you feel like it.